# ASP.NET cache solution for load-balancing system

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, caching, load-balancing

We are developing an ASP.NET web application on load-balancing system. Now we are facing several problems with current cache system:

1. It is not synchronized between web servers. There are some solutions such as SQL Cache Dependency or implementing a separated Cache Service:

   - SQL Cache Dependency: it is stable but quite slow for our app
   - Separated Cache Service: it is faster but not stable because we will have bottle-neck problem. Do you have any solution for this issue?
2. When we upgrade the Database system to Clustered servers, what is the stable solution for Cache system?

Thanks.

Comment: Windows Server AppFabric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use memcached and have had no problems with it.  Very reliable and pretty simple to implement.  What do you mean you'll have a bottle-neck problem with a third party caching solution?  We've been running it for about a year or so now and have had great experience with it.

Edit:
Our environment is load balanced across 3 web servers and 2 SQL servers.

The other reason I would prefer third party is because you can cache anything in it, objects, data, etc.

Setup: http://syntaxhelp.com/ASP.NET/Cache/memcache
References: http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewStart

Comment: Thanks for your share, Robert. Did you implement memcache on all of 3 web servers? Is there any way to synchronize memcache between them?

Comment: Ex: When a data record is updated (from 1 web server), how do I notify the 2 others?

Comment: No it's not running on all three servers, I believe we have it running on a separate server (I wasn't in on implementation) so when a record is updated there is no updating the others as to what is cached.

Answer (score 3):

Have seen NCache. It is free(the Express version. For Professional and Enterprise just Developer Machine is free ) and asp.net compatible.

NCache is an extremely fast and scalable in-memory distributed cache that caches application data . NCache also stores ASP.NET Session State Sessions in web farms. Works grate with Loadbalancer and simple to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Memcache is good for most use cases, but if you have many servers (each holding a shard of the total memcache pool) thats going to end up creating significant network traffic as the data has to go from the server where its held to where its used.

In some high read / low write use cases it might be better having every server holding a local copy of all the most heavily used data, then have a seperate service responsible for reliably updating all the copies.